# How to send an Array from AppController to RootViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

The appDelegate creates an MSMutableArray from some content downloaded from internet.

This array should be displayed in the RootViewController of the NavigationController ( a UITableView).

What's a correct workflow?
Send a message to the RootViewController to reload the data and pass the array from the appController to the RootViewController?

In the appDelegate:

```
[self.RootViewController loadArray: myArray];
```

In RootViewController:

```
-(void) loadArray: (NSArray *)theArray {
    self.array = theArray;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In reverse you can make it as delegate, but you approach seems to be better.